# Navigating Back In Navigation Controller/Not Reaching Root

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I may have designed myself into a corner here, but I am seeking some insight in navigating backwards in a Navigation Controller stack.  In my storyboard, I have a layout like so;

[image: Navigation Controller Layout]

The second Table View segues to itself, allowing a user to navigate forward an unlimited number of times, dependent on what is being populated in the table.  This is working properly.

I have implemented a **Back** button on my second Table View, which is hooked up to a *goBack* action, like so;

```
@IBAction func goBack(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This works properly for navigating back though all of the "looped segues" (I don't have a better term for this), but the back button will only go back to the first instance of the second Table View controller, and never back to the first Table View controller.  While I realize I do not have a segue for going back to the first Table View controller, I am trying to figure out a way have the same **Back** button in the second Table View go back to the first Table View Controller, once it has popped back through each of its own subsequent Table Views.

I did try `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` in my *goBack* function, but this will immediately take me back to the first Table View Controller, and never iterate back through any of the 2nd (or programatic 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc.) one step at a time.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't know the exact reason, but you can do a work around. When you navigate back to the last table VC of second table, you can use popToRootViewControllerAnimated() to go back to initial table.

Comment: That is what I was after doing, @Amit89, but I can't seem to figure out how I would use the same **Back** button to be able to do both `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` and `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`; the app never seems to know which VC I'm actually on.

Comment: If you have a method for back button, you can have a check how many view controller's in your navigation stack. If there are two means you moved back to first one of list of second table VCs. Use navigationController!.ViewControllers.count to find count.

Comment: Thanks, @Amit89.  I gave this a try, doing `let currentVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.count` followed by `print("You are currently on View Controller: \(currentVC!)")`.  It seems that when I go **forward** in my VCs, the count is updating properly, but when I go back, the count is not updating.  (For example, if my first TableView Controller = 1, my second TableViewController = 2, my second segued TableViewController = 3, then I go back from 3 to 2, the count remains at 2)...hmm...

Comment: Nevermind; I got it working.  I ended up getting rid of my second TableViewController altogether since it wasn't necessary and now this works as I wish!  THANK YOU!